# Changing a form value when submitting

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using Javascript to change an input value before submitting and saving it into a MySQL table, but after changing the value I get a blank row in the database.

I'm using it like this

```
document.getElementsByName('wifestatus').value  = "nothing";
```

I tried `getElementsById` but it gives me the same result.

```
    <td> <input type="radio" name="gotmarried" id="gotmarried1" value="لا" style="margin-right:5px" 
onClick="disablewifestatus()"/> </td>
<td> <label style="margin-right:5px"> <b>****</b> </label> </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="gotmarried" id="gotmarried2" value="****" style="margin-right:5px" 
onClick="enablewifestatus()"/> </td>
<td> <label style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px"> <b>*****</b> </label> </td>
<td> ( </td>  <td><input type="radio" name="wifestatus" id="wifestatus1" value="******" style="margin-right:5px"/> </td>
<td> <label style="margin-right:5px"> <b> **** </b> </label> </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="wifestatus" id="wifestatus2" value="*****" style="margin-right:5px"/> </td>
<td><label style="margin-right:5px"> <b> ***** </b> </label> </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="wifestatus" id="wifestatus3" value="****" style="margin-right:5px"/> </td>
<td> <label style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px"> <b>***** </b> </label> </td> <td>  ) </td>
```

I'm using Joomla so sending process will be like this

```
$row->gotmarried = $_POST['gotmarried'];
 $row->wifestatus = $_POST['wifestatus'];
```

How can I change the value of a form input and save it into the database?

Comment: You need to provide us with more relevant code, specifically: code that adds a row to the database and part of the HTML showing "wifestatus"

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer

Comment: are you trying to change the status of a radio button to selected?

Comment: what do you mean "if yes"? I am trying to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getElementById`, not `getElement(s)ById`

Furthermore, when you `getElements` by some selector, it doesn't just return that element(s) it returns an array like object that you would need to loop through to change values on.

http://jsfiddle.net/vhuumox0/17/

Comment: Sir, it's work only with input field but when I send it to the database it will send blank value.